# INSERT OR REPLACE does not update the record in SQLITE

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to insert the record in the database and whenever I do so, it inserts the record twice in the database.
I am using the following query to do my insert:

```
-(void) insert {
      NSString *sqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO test(ID,KEY ) VALUES ('%d','%@');", test.id, test.key];
      const char *insert_sql = [sqlQuery UTF8String];
      sqlite3_exec(db, insert_sql, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

It always enters duplicate records whenever I run this query. Is there a way to check if the data already exists then donot insert just update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're initializing the SQL string using `stringWithFormat:` but the string you pass is not a format string. The `?` parameters are only recognized by the sqlite parser.

You can fix this either by replacing the SQL string with

```
// Assuming id is an int and key is a string
NSString *sqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO test(ID,KEY ) VALUES (%d,%@);", test.id, test.key];
```

Or you need to call the sqlite prepare / bind functions to bind the parameters to the wildcards. For this see the [prepare](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) and [bind](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) documentation.

I suggest the second way, as this prevents SQL injection.

Comment: Hello Frenetisch. Sorry for the typo. And yeah I guess bind will help me to avoid SQL Injection. I may look into that direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is ID a primary key for the table, or otherwise indexed?  It needs to be unique for a replacement to occur.

Comment: Yes. Its a Unique Identifier.

Comment: If it is, then it's not possible to get duplicate records... either the IDs are different in ways you are not noticing, or the schema is wrong.

Comment: ID is actually UUID of 36 chars long and its always unique. The issue comes in only when I run the application and parse my XML file, I call this method to do insert and replace or update with new data. but it always increments the count of the data.

Comment: I am telling you, if the data model actually has entries marked as unique and the data has all unique values, it is not possible to have two rows in the database with the same UID.  If you are seeing more UIDs in the end than you have data something is wrong in your schema or your data.

Comment: Hey Kendall. Sorry for the confusion. I have UIDs but the issue is it is UIDs on the server side and there is no declaration of the UIDs on iphone database schema. How do you define it as UIDs in SQLITE?

Comment: When you create your schema you need to specify the column as unique, e.g. CREATE TABLE test (id UNIQUE, key).